# Docker-Py log with tail option is not working

Tags: python-3.x, docker, tail, dockerpy, python-docker

I'm trying to perform an automation using docker package of python. In that I tried to read the logs with tails with below code, But it is showing nothing.

```
import docker
z=docker.from_env()
dkg = z.containers.get('<container_id>').logs(stream = True, follow = False, tail =10)
while True:
    line = next(dkg).decode("utf-8")
    print(line)
```

It would be helpful if you could identify the missing item in my code.
Thanks in Advance  for going through the question

Comment: Is this still an issue? I recently made a comment in an [issue](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/2913#issuecomment-1448310972) on github that could possibly help.

Answer (score 0):

That code should work well.

The `follow=True` will keep waiting for more data; maybe that can help you.

Also, **be sure that the data** is being written to **stdout**.

I suggest changing the loop like this:

```py
for line in dkg:
    print(line.decode())
```

That will avoid the `StopIteration` Exception.